# Please help! How do I transfer my wallet from bitcoin core to MultibitHD?

Tags: blockchain, wallet, bitcoin-core, multibit, wallet.dat

I (should by now) have bitcoins in my wallet,I sent them to my wallet whilst i was using bitcoin core but after taking days to sync (and it still hasn't synced) i have given up and installed multibitHD. I have tried using blockchain to import the data file but it keeps saying connection refused even thought the password is correct and the file is fine.

Now Bitcoincore wont even open so i cannot check whether it has synced or whether my bitcoins are still there and I'm beginning to worry that I've lost my money can someone please help me transfer my bitcoin core wallet over to multibitHD!?

Answer (score -1):

Put request in multibithd. Scan or put the address shown and put it in the btc core and make sure the receiving amount in multibithd is the same as the sending amount in btccore. No fees thats for sure